# HTTP Status 500 - NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, http

I've been getting this error and I haven't found a way to come around it yet.
Seems to be something regarding the scanner, but I'm not sure what to change here.

My LoginServlet:

```
package web;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ______________________________________________________________
        boolean loginSuccess = false;
        String naam = "";
        String pass = "";
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        String operator = req.getParameter("operator");

        if (operator.equals("Register")) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("Register.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        // _________________________*******_________________________________

        // ___________________scanner declaratie________
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("users.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        // _________________________*******____________

        // ___________________!! Lezen van file !!________________________
        if (operator.equals("Login")) {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String regel = sc.nextLine();
                sc.useDelimiter("\\s:\\s");
                naam = sc.next();
                pass = sc.next();

                System.out.println(naam);
                System.out.println(pass);
                // ___________________Toevoegen aan logged users_____
                if (req.getParameter("username").equals(naam)
                        && (req.getParameter("password").equals(pass))) {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter("loggedusers.txt", true)));

                    out.println(naam);
                    out.close();
                    loginSuccess = true;
                    break;
                } else if (req.getParameter("username").equals(naam)
                        && (!req.getParameter("password").equals(pass))) {
                    req.setAttribute("error", "Password incorrect");
                    loginSuccess = false;
                    break;
                } else if (!sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    req.setAttribute("error", "Username doesn't exist");
                    loginSuccess = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            sc.close();

            if (loginSuccess = true) {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            } else if (loginSuccess = false) {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

My Login.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet.do" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Username:</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password:</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="operator" value="Register" /></td>
                <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="operator" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
    <h1><%=request.getAttribute("error") %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The web.xml should be correct because it worked before, but after writing the rest of the code from the servlet, it jams.

The error it gives me in Eclipse:

```
jun 03, 2015 4:44:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Dynamic Example Servlet] in context with path [/DynamicExample] threw exception
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at web.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And a screenshot of what I see in my browser when I run it:
[image: http://puu.sh/iaWY9/5b0da53a66.png]

I'd love to hear from you guys!
Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your "users.txt" file?

Comment: First guess is that your *users.txt* file contains bogus data which is not compatible with your "\\s:\\s" pattern. I'd also suggest to: 1) Use try-with to open close the Scanner (remember it is not thread-safe); 2) Invert all the literals comparisons e.g. if ("Register".equals(operator)). 3) Add a try catch to filter bogus data and prevent your web app to stop.

Comment: A direct download link to the users.txt:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=39858690815462995799&t=3985869081546299579911025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look before you leap.  Or more accurately, **don't double-advance your `Scanner`.**

These lines are the culprit:

```
String regel = sc.nextLine();
naam = sc.next();
pass = sc.next();
```

`hasNextLine()` is valid for the call to `nextLine()`, but not to subsequent `next()` calls.

What you *probably* want to do is read out the `naam` and `paas` values from `regel` instead.

```
String regel = sc.nextLine();
String[] regelBroken = regel.split();
naam = regelBroken[0];
paas = regelBroken[1];
```

This way, you only ever advance the scanner once, so you don't run into a scenario in which you're out of things to scan.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an empty line at the end of "*users.txt*"?

On last iteration, that could cause `naam = sc.next();` throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I tried it a little different:

```js
FileReader fr = new FileReader("users.txt");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

   while (true) {
    String regel = br.readLine();
    if (regel == null) {
     break;
    }
    sc = new Scanner(regel);
    sc.useDelimiter("\\s:\\s");
    naam = sc.next();
    pass = sc.next();
```

It works!

Thanks for the solution with the arrays, I saved that piece of code, I think I might try such method later on, thanks everyone!